# I need help to structure the python csv to json in the following format, pease

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

Please I need help and this is all I have achieved so far

```
csvfile = open('new_df.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('new_df.csv'.replace('.csv','.json'), 'w')

jsonfile.write('{"' + 'new_df.csv'.replace('.csv','') + '": [\n')       # write json parent of data list
fieldnames = csvfile.readline().replace('\n','').split(',')                         # get fieldnames from first line of csv
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('new_df.csv')) - 1                                   # count total lines in csv minus header row

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)                                        
i = 0
for row in reader:
  i += 1
  json.dump(row, jsonfile)
  if i < num_lines:
    jsonfile.write(',')
  jsonfile.write('\n')
jsonfile.write(']}')

ID       Arrival       Departure    ArrivalDate       DepatureDate 
1001     New York      Holland       2009-09-23           2012-07-23
1301     Florida       Germany       2010-10-23          2012-10-11
1401     New York      Holland       2009-09-23          2009-09-25
1301     New York      Beijing       2009-09-23         2010-09-21
1201     New York      Holland       2008-01-01         2009-09-23
1001     Virginia      New York      2008-01-01         2009-09-22
1021     New York      Holland       2009-09-23         2009-09-25 
1001     New York      Holland       2009-09-24         2012-07-23
1021     New York      Holland       2009-09-26         2012-07-23
1001     New York      Holland       2009-09-25         2012-07-23
…....    .........     ........      ..............      ...........

1001     New York         Holland              2012-07-23         2012-07-23
1401     New York         Holland              2009-09-25         2009-09-25
1301     New York         Beijing              2010-09-21         2010-09-21
1201     New York         Holland              2009-09-23         2009-09-23
1001     Virginia         New York             2009-09-22         2009-09-22
1021     New York         Holland              2009-09-25         2009-09-25 
1001     New York         Holland              2012-07-23         2012-07-23
1021     New York         Holland              2012-07-23         2012-07-23
1001     New York         Holland              2012-07-23         2012-07-23
```

Iterate through `ArrivalDate` and append the equivalent rows as follows, then Expected output:
             i.e.

```
"{ArrivalDate:" { "Arrival": ID1,...,IDn
                                   "Departure": ID1,...,IDn 
                                     }
```

(I need to check under **DepartureDate** if it matches with **ArrivalDate**, if it does match, I want to append its ID to the Departure otherwise "Arrival" will only be listed

```
       {
          “2009-09-23”:
                                   { “New York”: 1001, 1401, 1301, 1021,
                “Holland” :  1021,
                                       “Beijing”:  1301,
                                      }
      { “2010-10-23”:
                                  {“Florida”: 1301, 
                                  }
     { “2008-01-01”:
                                {“New York”: 1201,
                                  “Virginia”: 1001,
        }
     {“2009-09-24”:
        {“New York”: 1001
        }
     {“2009-09-26”: 
        {“New York”: 1021
        }
     {“2009-09-25”:
                               {“New York”: 1001 
                                  “Holland”: 1401
                                  }
     {“ 2012-07-23”: 
                              { “New York”: 1001,
                             “Holland”: 1001,
```

Comment: Check if `DepartureDate` falls between what?

Comment: The condition to have any ID appended to "Departure" in the JSON format, since i'm considering ArrivalDate, I want to check if the DepartureDate matches with Arrival on a given row and it does match, I want to append it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

json_dict = {}
for arrival_date, data in df.groupby('ArrivalDate'):
    matching_dates = data[data.DepatureDate==arrival_date]
    not_matching_dates = data[data.DepatureDate!=arrival_date]
    json_dict[arrival_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')] = {}
    if not matching_dates.empty:
        for city, flights in matching_dates.groupby('Arrival'):
            json_dict[arrival_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')][city] = [str(v) for v in flights.ID.to_dict().values()]
    if not not_matching_dates.empty:
        for city, flights in not_matching_dates.groupby('Departure'):
            json_dict[arrival_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')][city] = [str(v) for v in flights.ID.to_dict().values()]
```

Assuming you want `json` output:

```
print(json.dumps(json_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

{
    "2008-01-01": {
        "Holland": [
            "1201"
        ],
        "New York": [
            "1001"
        ]
    },
    "2009-09-22": {
        "Virginia": [
            "1001"
        ]
    },
    "2009-09-23": {
        "Beijing": [
            "1301"
        ],
        "Holland": [
            "1001",
            "1401",
            "1021"
        ],
        "New York": [
            "1201"
        ]
    },
    "2009-09-24": {
        "Holland": [
            "1001"
        ]
    },
    "2009-09-25": {
        "Holland": [
            "1001"
        ],
        "New York": [
            "1021",
            "1001",
            "1401"
        ]
    },
    "2009-09-26": {
        "Holland": [
            "1021"
        ]
    },
    "2010-09-21": {
        "New York": [
            "1301"
        ]
    },
    "2010-10-23": {
        "Germany": [
            "1301"
        ]
    },
    "2012-07-23": {
        "New York": [
            "1001",
            "1001",
            "1021",
            "1001"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow Stefan! I love u so much. Thank you for rescuing me

Comment: Sir, sorry I have issue the script. I want to reuse it but displaying differently